# ValueError: view limit minimum -0.001 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got data from a meteorological station to plot including temperature-, pressure- and radiation- measurements. When trying to plot the different datapoints I always get this error...even though the code works for another station with the exact same parameters but (obviously) different measurements.
I have tryed everything but cant find the source of the problem. I hope someone can help me!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt



datenmodelo = pd.read_csv('1163655_010319_OZ_ALL_2.csv', sep=';', usecols=['Monat','Datum', 'Zeit', 'T_oM', 'RH_oM', 'T_uM', 'RH_uM', 'p_M', 'G_M', 'PAR_M'])

daten_si_M = datenmodelo.set_index(['Datum'])     
dfmt1 = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M') 
x_date_M = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%d.%m.%Y').date() for d in dates_M]


a = 0

start = 0
end = 1

for daysM in dates_M[start:end]:  

 # Definition aller Funktionswerte/Größen (eingeschlossen NaN)
    T_uMd= pd.to_numeric(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].T_uM, errors='coerce')    
    T_oMd = pd.to_numeric(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].T_oM, errors='coerce')   
    RH_uMd = pd.to_numeric(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].RH_uM, errors='coerce')     
    RH_oMd = pd.to_numeric(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].RH_oM, errors='coerce')   
    G_Md = pd.to_numeric(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].G_M, errors='coerce')
    p_Md = pd.to_numeric(p_M_korr.loc[daysM], errors='coerce')    
    PAR_Md= pd.to_numeric(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].PAR_M, errors='coerce')


    x_time_M = pd.to_datetime(daten_si_M.loc[daysM].Zeit) 


    f, axarr = plt.subplots(4,1)                           
    f.set_size_inches(15, 20)                                           


 # Titel der Graphen und Achsen:
    axarr[0].set_title('Modelo - %s'%daysM, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    axarr[3].set_xlabel('Uhrzeit',  fontweight='bold')
    axarr[1].set_ylabel('T [°C]',  fontweight='bold')
    axarr[2].set_ylabel('RH [%]',  fontweight='bold')
    axarr[0].set_ylabel('G [W/m^2]',  fontweight='bold')
    axarr[3].set_ylabel('p [hPa]',  fontweight='bold')

 # Formatierung der Achsen:
    axarr[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt1)    
    axarr[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt1)
    axarr[2].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt1)
    axarr[3].xaxis.set_major_formatter(dfmt1)

 # Plot der Variablen und Label der Kurve:
    axarr[1].plot(x_time_M, T_uMd,'r', label='Temperatur (unten)')
    axarr[1].plot(x_time_M, T_oMd, color='indigo', label='Temperatur (oben)')
    axarr[2].plot(x_time_M, RH_uMd,'r', label='Relative Feuchte (unten)')
    axarr[2].plot(x_time_M, RH_oMd,color='indigo', label='Relative Feuchte (oben)')
    axarr[0].plot(x_time_M, G_Md,'b', label='Globalstrahlung')
    axarr[0].plot(x_time_M, PAR_Md,'c', label='Photosynthetische Strahlung')    
    axarr[3].plot(x_time_M, p_Md,'g', label='Druck')

 # Positionierung der Labels:
    axarr[0].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5))
    axarr[1].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5))
    axarr[2].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5))
    axarr[3].legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.5))

 # Gitter:
    plt.rc('grid', linestyle="dashed", color='b', alpha=0.5, linewidth=0.5)
    plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True

 # Plot:
    plt.savefig('Modelo (GTRHp) - %s.png' %(str(daysM)), bbox_inches='tight', dpi=300)
    plt.close()
    a += 1
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your symptom looks similar to [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13588) known bug.  I can't confirm because your code looks incomplete.  You don't show what `dates_M` is, for example. 
 Ignoring that, I'd look at the values in `x_time_M`.  I expect they're all something like [`numpy.nan`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.nan).  Then look at `daten_si_M` to find out why.

Regardless, here's a much simpler case of the bug I think you (and I) are seeing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.plot([np.nan])

plt.show()
```

That triggers the same exception you saw.

```
ValueError: view limit minimum -0.001 is less than 1 and is an invalid
Matplotlib date value.  This often happens if you pass a non-datetime to
an axis that has datetime units
```

Changing the plot call to this works fine.

```
ax.plot([])
```

If I understand, `matplotlib` date values cannot be less than 1.  In this example, all the coordinates (only one here) are `numpy.nan`, which causes the view limits to be set to (-0.001, 0.001), neither of which can be used as a date, triggering the exception.

I'm having the same problem in my own code, which uses `matplotlib` 2.2.2, and don't have the option of upgrading.  The only workaround I've come up with is to set the limits on the *x*-axis when I detect this case.

```
...
ax.set_xlim(now,now+oneDay)
...
```

The range makes no difference in my case, because there's nothing better, given that all the *x*-coordinates are `numpy.nan`.

Good luck.